# C++ template recursion undefined type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have templates for instructions like add, store, jump, return and variable. Then I created static_list template for storing these instructions. I want to execute them one by one. I use enable_if_else and comparing member instruction for checking what type the current instruction is and branch accordingly. However, I cant continue after the first check, if it is a variable type instruction. The execute_v and execute_s are working when it is like this:

```
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s <index, static_list<Commands ...>> {
    static constexpr int value = enable_if_else_v < static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 1,
                                    1,
                                    0>::result ;
};
```

It returns 1 or 0 depending on what type of instruction I put as first into execute_v. This works correctly. However when I want to recursively continue onto next command, it wont work, it looks like this:

```
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s <index, static_list<Commands ...>> {
    static constexpr int value = enable_if_else_v < static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 1,
                                    execute_s<index + 1, Commands...>::value,
                                    0>::result ;
};
```

The problem is with `execute_s<index + 1, Commands...>::value` as it seems it does not stop when instruction is not variable type, but I dont know why is it so, because it should stop then. Maybe I am wrongly unpacking Commands? How can I achieve that I can push forward next index with all the commands to the next level of recursion?
These are the templates:

```
template<size_t VariableId, int InitValue>
struct variable {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr int value = InitValue;
    static constexpr int instruction = 1;
};

template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct store {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 2;
};

template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct add {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 3;
};

template<size_t VariableId, size_t CommandNumber>
struct jump_if_not_zero {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr size_t commandNumber = CommandNumber;
    static constexpr int instruction = 4;
};

template<size_t VariableId>
struct ret {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 5;
};

//-------------enable_if_else_v-------------
template<bool Cond, int TrueValue, int FalseValue>
struct enable_if_else_v;

template<int TrueValue, int FalseValue>
struct enable_if_else_v<true, TrueValue, FalseValue> {
    static constexpr int result = TrueValue;
};

template<int TrueValue, int FalseValue>
struct enable_if_else_v<false, TrueValue, FalseValue> {
    static constexpr int result = FalseValue;
};

//-------------static_list_get-------------
template<size_t Idx, class List>
struct static_list_get;

template<size_t Idx, class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<Idx, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>>
    : static_list_get<Idx - 1, static_list<Elements ...>> {
};

template<class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<1, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>> {
    using type = FirstElement;
};

//-------------execute_s-------------
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s;

template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s <index, static_list<Commands ...>> {
    static constexpr int value = enable_if_else_v < static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 1,
                                    execute_s<index + 1, Commands...>::value,
                                    0>::result ;
};

template<class ...Commands>
constexpr int execute_v = execute_s<1, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
```

And this is main function example:

```
int main() {
    constexpr size_t PREV = 0;
    constexpr size_t CURR = 1;
    constexpr size_t OLD_CURR = 2;
    constexpr size_t N = 3;
    constexpr size_t MINUS1 = 4;
    
    constexpr int fib_n = execute_v<
        variable<PREV, 0>,              // 1: PREV = 0
        variable<CURR, 1>,              // 2: CURR = 1
        variable<OLD_CURR, 0>,          // 3: OLD_CURR = 0
        variable<N, 10>,                // 4: N = 10
        variable<MINUS1, -1>,           // 5: MINUS1 = -1

        jump_if_not_zero<N, 8>,         // 6: if (N > 0) goto 8
        ret<PREV>,                      // 7: return 0

        store<OLD_CURR, CURR>,          // 8: OLD_CURR = CURR
        add<CURR, PREV>,                // 9: CURR += PREV
        store<PREV, OLD_CURR>,          // 10: PREV = OLD_CURR
        add<N, MINUS1>,                 // 11: N += -1
        jump_if_not_zero<N, 8>,         // 12: if (N > 0) goto 8
        ret<PREV>                       // 13: return PREV
    >;
    static_assert(fib_n == 55, "Wrong result");
}
```

Compile errors:
use of undefined type 'execute_s<2, variable<0, 0>, variable<1, 1>, variable<2, 0>...(all commands)..., ret<0>>'

I tried to pack Commands to list like this: `execute_s<index + 1, static_list<Commands...>>::value`, but it was not working, it does not stop the recursion.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding lies in that you think that somehow only one branch of `enable_if_else` is evaluated, when in fact both are. Which means there's nothing to stop your recursion. You could probably use SFINAE instead.

Comment: how could be evaluated both of them? for simple examples it worked.
how can I use SFINAE?

Comment: Even if only one of them are chosen, both has to be evaluated.

Comment: I see, but I dont know how to use SFINAE, could you please show me how it could be used there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a bit incomplete, but I'll try to give you the general idea with SFINAE.

```
template <bool condition, int index, typename list>
struct get_next_command_or_zero;

template <int index, typename list>
struct get_next_command_or_zero<false, index, list> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
}

template <int index, typename... Commands>
struct get_next_command_or_zero<true, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, Commands...>::value; // I think you example is wrong here since, execure_s is expecting a static_list?
}
```

Here we use sfinae to pick the right partial specialization first, so the lookup of `execure_s<...>::value` is only done when that path is chosen and otherwise discarded and left unevaluated.

Now in `execute_s` you can use this like

```
static constexpr int value = get_next_command_or_zero<static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 1, index, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So SFINAE is just packing that execute_s inside another template so it wont be executed if no needed?

Comment: Yes, the evaluation of the condition and choosing of specialization is done first. The evaluation of the next command is only done within one of the specialization so it's defered until after we know if it's needed or not.

Comment: May I ask you for help with store command too? How can I take the static_list<Commands...> and change one variable value in it by source variableId given? I tried to use SFINAE there too but it got complicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357322/c-variadic-template-change-element-in-middle