# C++ variadic template change element in middle

Tags: c++, templates

I have templates for instructions like add, store, jump, return and variable. Then I created static_list template for storing these instructions. I want to execute them one by one. I use SFINAE and comparing member instruction for checking what type the current instruction is and branch accordingly.
These are the templates:

```
template<size_t VariableId, int InitValue>
struct variable {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr int value = InitValue;
    static constexpr int instruction = 1;
};

template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct store {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 2;
};

template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct add {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 3;
};

template<size_t VariableId, size_t CommandNumber>
struct jump_if_not_zero {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr size_t commandNumber = CommandNumber;
    static constexpr int instruction = 4;
};

template<size_t VariableId>
struct ret {
    static constexpr size_t variableId = VariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 5;
};



//-------------static_list-------------
template<class ...Elements>
struct static_list {};

//-------------static_list_get-------------
template<size_t Idx, class List>
struct static_list_get;

template<size_t Idx, class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<Idx, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>>
    : static_list_get<Idx - 1, static_list<Elements ...>> {
};

template<class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<1, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>> {
    using type = FirstElement;
};



//-------------variable_command_or_try_store-------------
template <bool condition, int index, typename list>
struct variable_command_or_try_store;

//-------------store_command_or_try_add-------------
template <bool condition, int index, typename list>
struct store_command_or_try_add;

//-------------execute_s-------------
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s;



//-------------variable_command_or_try_store-------------
template <int index, typename ... Commands>
struct variable_command_or_try_store<false, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = store_command_or_try_add<static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 2, index, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
};

template <int index, typename... Commands>
struct variable_command_or_try_store<true, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
};

//-------------store_command_or_try_add-------------
template <int index, typename ... Commands>
struct store_command_or_try_add<false, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <int index, typename... Commands>
struct store_command_or_try_add<true, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, NEW LIST WITH ONE CHANGED VALUE>::value;
};


//-------------execute_s-------------
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s <index, static_list<Commands ...>> {
    static constexpr int value = variable_command_or_try_store<static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::instruction == 1, index, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
};

template<class ...Commands>
constexpr int execute_v = execute_s<1, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
```

And this is main function example:

```
int main() {
    constexpr size_t PREV = 0;
    constexpr size_t CURR = 1;
    constexpr size_t OLD_CURR = 2;
    constexpr size_t N = 3;
    constexpr size_t MINUS1 = 4;
    
    constexpr int fib_n = execute_v<
        variable<PREV, 0>,              // 1: PREV = 0
        variable<CURR, 1>,              // 2: CURR = 1
        variable<OLD_CURR, 0>,          // 3: OLD_CURR = 0
        variable<N, 10>,                // 4: N = 10
        variable<MINUS1, -1>,           // 5: MINUS1 = -1

        jump_if_not_zero<N, 8>,         // 6: if (N > 0) goto 8
        ret<PREV>,                      // 7: return 0

        store<OLD_CURR, CURR>,          // 8: OLD_CURR = CURR
        add<CURR, PREV>,                // 9: CURR += PREV
        store<PREV, OLD_CURR>,          // 10: PREV = OLD_CURR
        add<N, MINUS1>,                 // 11: N += -1
        jump_if_not_zero<N, 8>,         // 12: if (N > 0) goto 8
        ret<PREV>                       // 13: return PREV
    >;
    static_assert(fib_n == 55, "Wrong result");
}
```

I want to repeatedly cycle through command types and if the type fits then execute the command and start over with next command in list. Currently I have implemented only command variable which just continues without doing anything because I already have it stored from beginning.
Next, if it is not variable type I check if it is store type. Again if not continue checking other command (not implemented yet). If it is store command, then continue on next command in list but with changed list, the value of destinationVar will be changed to sourceVar value by store command.
How can I achieve this? I tried something like this using SFINAE but it is not working:

```
//-------------static_list_store-------------
template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class OldList>
struct static_list_store;

//-------------is_var_or_no_change-------------
template <bool Cond, size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class OldList>
struct is_var_or_no_change;

//-------------is_id_or_no_change-------------
template <bool Cond, size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class OldList>
struct is_id_or_no_change;

template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class ...OldElements>
struct is_var_or_no_change<false, from, to, NewElements, Element, static_list<OldElements...>> {
    using type = static_list_store<from, to, static_list<NewElements, Element>, OldElements...>;
};

template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class ...OldElements>
struct is_var_or_no_change<true, from, to, NewElements, Element, static_list<OldElements...>> {
    using type = is_id_or_no_change<Element::variableId == to, from, to, static_list<NewElements, Element>, OldElements...>;
};

//-------------is_id_or_no_change-------------
template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class ...OldElements>
struct is_id_or_no_change<false, from, to, NewElements, Element, static_list<OldElements...>> {
    using type = static_list_store<from, to, static_list<NewElements, Element>, OldElements...>;
};

template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class ...OldElements>
struct is_id_or_no_change<true, from, to, NewElements, Element, static_list<OldElements...>> {
    using type = static_list_store<from, to, static_list<NewElements, variable<Element::variableId, /*find var by id ::value for now 16*/16>>, OldElements...>;
};

//-------------static_list_store-------------
template<size_t from, size_t to, class NewElements, class Element, class ...OldElements>
struct static_list_store<from, to, NewElements, Element, static_list<OldElements...>> {
    using type = is_var_or_no_change<Element::instruction == 1, from, to, static_list<NewElements, Element>, OldElements...>;
};
```

and then store_command_or_try_add will be:

```
template <int index, typename... Commands>
struct store_command_or_try_add<true, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, static_list_store<static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::sourceVariableId, static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands...>>::type::destinationVariableId, static_list<>, static_list<Commands...>>>::value;
};
```

Comment: Should that last `execute_s` use a `typename static_list_store<...>::type` instead of the `static_list_store` directly? I don't actually see any SFINAE here, just partial specializations. Instead of doing an else-if-heimer's sequence, what about specializing a single `typename exec_one_cmd<Command, ExecContext>::result` with `exec_one_cmd<variable<Id, InitValue>, Ctx>`, `exec_one_cmd<store<DestVarId, SrcVarId>, Ctx>`, etc.?

Comment: how can I make `exec_one_cmd<variable<Id, InitValue>, Ctx>` ? it wont allow me to write it like that
instead I tried
`template <bool varC, bool strC, bool addC, bool jumpC, bool retC, int index, typename list>
struct execute_command;`
where I have all conditions and everytime only 1 of them is true, could it be like that?

Comment: Sorry, that was shortened notation. The idea would be more like `template <typename Command, typename ExecContext> struct exec_one_cmd;` then specialization `template <size_t Id, int InitValue, typename ExecContext> struct exec_one_cmd<variable<Id, InitValue>, ExecContext> { using result = ...; };`

Comment: Yeah, I get the idea, thanks.
Do you know how should I implement the store command for example? The add command will nearly the same. Return is just ending with value and jump only changing index. But how can I change only one command from variadic list by id stored in another command?

Comment: Probably the main thing there is design of the `ExecContext` type. I'd probably have a key helper piece doing something like `template<__> struct replace_value<KeyId, NewVal, static_list<variable<Id, OldVal>...>> { using values = static_list<std::conditional_t<(Id==KeyId), variable<Id, NewVal>, variable<Id, OldVal>>...>; };`